# Searching recursively batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to utilize the if exist control statement to search the entire file system to find a file.

```
@echo off
echo Enter a file name......
set /P file=
set searchPath=C:\
set findit=%searchPath% and %file%

IF EXIST C:\*%%findit%% (
    echo file exist 
  )else (
    echo file does not exist
  )
```

However, if I search for a file that does exist, I still get the same search results of file does not exist.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `set findit=%searchPath% and %file%` sets `%findit%` to something like `C:\ and file.ext`. And you really should rethink your `if exist` line. Change `echo off` to `echo on` to watch your code running

Comment: @Compo, instead of `else` you mean `||`, right?

Comment: Instead of `If Exist` use `Dir /B /S /A:-D "%searchPath%\%file%" 1> NUL 2>&1 && (Echo File exists.) || Echo File does not exist`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Where /R "[dir]" /Q "Pattern"`

This allows you to search a directory path and return all of the matching files.

`IF Exist` check can't check for a file glob

But you also need to address that this line `findit=%searchPath% and %file%` was setting `%Findit%` equal to the string `"findit=C:\ and %file%"`

**Here is a cleaned up version which seems to be what you're looking for:**

```
@echo off
echo 
set /P "_File=Enter a file name......"
set "_SearchPath=C:\"

(
  Where /R "%_SearchPath%" /Q "%_File%" && (
    ECHO.File %_File% Exists!
  )
) || (
  ECHO.File %_File% Does Not Exist!
)
```